# How to save results from a loop separately?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, visual-studio-code

I need my results to be saved separately so that I can run the rest of my code.

Basically, I have to do a project on loans and each type of loan would have a different monthly repayment amount. The problem now is that each user might have a different number of different loans. For example, one user might only have home loan (HL) while one user might have 3 different loans. In my codes, I need to include this which would return the monthly repayment amount for that particular type of loan:

```
def meet_criteria(account_no):
    if getsaving(account_no) in ["HL"]:
        HLmonthly()
    else:
        if getsaving(account_no) in ["RL"]:
            RLmonthly()
        else:
            if getsaving(account_no) in ["EL"]:
                ELmonthly()
```

I also need to sum up the repayment amount like this:

```
total_monthly_debt = repay1 + repay2 + repay3
```

However, right now, I can't to proceed with above codes as I am unable to separate the results to get the 'HL', 'RL' and 'EL' that I need to call the meet criteria(). In order to get all the results to show, I am using a loop like so:

```
def getsaving(account_no): 
    query = """\
        select SUBSTRING(LoanID, 1, 2)
        from Account_Delinquency
        where Account_Number = '{}'
        """ .format(account_no)

    return (execute_read_query (conn, query))


a = getsaving(account_no)

mylist = []
for i in a:
    mylist.append(i)
```

I tried to put it in a list so that I could separate it but obviously, it doesn't work that way. This was a method I learnt to check if a list is empty but as expected, it can't check if parts of the list is empty and would return error. It also involves a little hardcoding which is not ideal.

```
if mylist[1][0]:
    loan1 = mylist[1][0]
else:
    pass
```

Hence, I am asking to see if there are any other methods I can use so that I can get a result of, for example, Loan1 = HL, Loan2 = nothing, Loan3 = RL etc. I would also appreciate any suggestions for changes to my code as I know it is not the most ideal. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try a dictionary `{'loan_type':number}`?

Answer (score 0):

#### `meet_criteria` seems incorect (no return value)

```
def meet_criteria(account_no):
    if getsaving(account_no) in ["HL"]:
        HLmonthly()
    else:
        if getsaving(account_no) in ["RL"]:
            RLmonthly()
        else:
            if getsaving(account_no) in ["EL"]:
                ELmonthly()
```

could be

```
def meet_criteria(account_no):
    if getsaving(account_no) == "HL":
        HLmonthly()
    elif getsaving(account_no) == "RL":
        RLmonthly()
    elif getsaving(account_no) == "EL":
        ELmonthly()
```

Btw. I haven't fully understood your question, but I think that you want `meet_criteria` to return something, (I would know for sure if you provided how you use this function).

So instead do

```
def meet_criteria(account_no):
    if getsaving(account_no) == "HL":
        return HLmonthly()
    elif getsaving(account_no) == "RL":
        return RLmonthly()
    elif getsaving(account_no) == "EL":
        return ELmonthly()
```

#### Further improvements:

```
if mylist[1][0]:
    loan1 = mylist[1][0]
else:
    pass
```

The `else` branch doesn't do anything. Also, if you haven't defined `loan1` before and you are using it later, you would get `NameError: name 'loan1' is not defined`.

To remove else branch:

```
if mylist[1][0]:
    loan1 = mylist[1][0]
```

To not get `NameError`

```
if mylist[1][0]:
    loan1 = mylist[1][0]
else:
    loan1 = 0  # if it is suposed to be integer, maybe you want None of False
```